# UITableView with data from NSMutableArray returns empty

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipickerview

I want to fill the content of a `TableView` according to selections made in a `PickerView` view. The code I have so far is:

```
- (IBAction)findOwnerButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    findShip.hidden = NO;
    shipOwners.hidden = NO;

    boatsTableView.hidden = YES;
    boatOwners = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Owner1",@"Owner2",@"Owner3", nil];
}

- (IBAction)findShipButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    shipOwners.hidden = YES;
    findShip.hidden = YES;
    boatsTableView.hidden = NO;
}
```

**PickerView Data Source**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [boatOwners count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
             titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
            forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [boatOwners objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

**PickerView Delegate**

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView 
      didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
       inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSString *boatsFromOwner = [boatOwners objectAtIndex:[shipOwners selectedRowInComponent:0]];
    boatsForOwner = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:nil];
    if ([boatsFromOwner isEqualToString:@"Owner1"]) {
        [self.boatsForOwner addObject:@"Titanic"];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",boatsFromOwner);
}
```

**TableView DataSource & Delegate**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [boatsForOwner count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [boatsForOwner objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

This is supposed to return the boat owner company from a `PickerWheel`, and give me their boats in the table. This code returns nothing in the table. The `PickerWheel` logs 'Owner1' when I select it.

Is my error in how I add objects to the array or how I initialize the table or how I compare `PickerWheel` result to a word?

Comment: Do you ever instantiate boatsForOwner?

Comment: Yep, in .h and synthesised

Comment: No, that's not an instantiation -- instantiation means an alloc init like in the answer you accepted.

Comment: oh ok sorry i didnt know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think first `alloc` & `init` the array "boatsForOwner "

replace your picker `didSelectRow`  method with

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView 
     didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
      inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSString *boatsFromOwner = [boatOwners objectAtIndex:[shipOwners selectedRowInComponent:0]];

    if(boatsForOwner) {
        [boatsForOwner release];
        boatsForOwner = nil;
    }

    boatsForOwner = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if ([boatsFromOwner isEqualToString:@"Owner1"]) {
        [self.boatsForOwner addObject:@"Titanic"];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@",boatsFromOwner);

    [tableObject reloadData];

}
```

and `release` `boatsForOwner` when you  `dealloc`.

Answer (score 2):

After you do

```
[self.boatsForOwner addObject:@"Titanic"];
```

You will manually need to refresh you tableview.. so after that do

```
[_yourTableView reloadData];
```

I would also initialize your arrays like this:

```
boatsForOwner = [NSMutableArray new];
```

Comment: Do I still need to do this when it is in the .h file and synthesized? (Initialize)

Comment: Are you talking about your UITableView property?

Comment: Oh Yes you still need to initialize it in code like I did. If you don't it won't give you an error or crash but nothing will ever actually get added to your array

Comment: Okai, thanks. Both of you guys helped me out, so I will upvote yours and accept the other guys because you got highest rep :)